# Spectrum of the laplacian on a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Is the spectrum of the laplacian on $L^1(0,1)$ with Neumann boundary conditions known?

Comment: Probably it's just me, but what do you mean exactly? The Laplacian is not an operator on $L^1(0,1)$.

Comment: The laplacian is defined in $L^1(0,1)$ as the generator of the extended semigrop on  $L^1(0,1)$ of the semigroup generated by the usual laplacian in  $L^2(0,1)$.

Comment: Oh. You misunderstood the point to my question. What's the Laplacian in $L^2(0,1)$ then?

Comment: In the case of $L^2(0,1)$,  $\Delta$ is an unbounded operator in $L^2(0,1)$ with domain  $D(\Delta)= \{y\in H^2(0,1); y'(0)=y'(1)=0\}$ and is defined via the inner product of $L^2(0,1)$ in the sens of  distribution .

Comment: Oh! It's just the (unbounded, etc) second derivative! Sorry, never thought of that as the "Laplacian" in one variable. Like I said, just me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show that the resolvent is
$$
     R(\lambda)f = \frac{\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}(1-x))}{\sqrt{\lambda}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda})}\int_{0}^{x}\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}t)f(t)dt+\frac{\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x)}{{\sqrt{\lambda}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda})}}\int_{x}^{1}\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}(1-t))dt.
$$
That is, $g=R(\lambda)f$ solves
$$
                      -g''-\lambda g = f \\
                      g'(0)=0,\;\;\; g'(1)=0,
$$
provided that $\lambda \ne n^2\pi^2$ for $n=0,1,2,3,\cdots$. The same resolvent expression works for $L^1$ and for $L^2$ if $L =-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$. So, in either case, the spectrum is a subset of $\{ n^2\pi^2 : n =0,1,2,3\cdots\}$. Conversely, every such point is in the spectrum because $L\cos(n\pi x)=n^2\pi^2\cos(n\pi x)$, which proves that $n^2\pi^2$ is an eigenvalue.